# Captcha session doesnt update sometimes

Tags: php, session, captcha

sometimes , when i refresh the page that including captcha image, captcha image loads with new string , but the `session` that including captcha sting , doesn't update !

for example , first , my captcha image shows `abcde`. next, i refresh the page , captcha image shows `vwxyz` as new captcha code and regularly , the value of `$_SESSION['rand_code']` should be replaced with 
`vwxyz`. but `$_SESSION['rand_code']` has the same value `abcde`

notice : this problem occurs 10% of the times.

catpcha.php :

```
<?php
if(!session_id() || session_id() == ''){ // i used this because i have started a session before
  session_start();
}
$string = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $string .= chr(mt_rand(97, 122));
}

$_SESSION['rand_code'] = $string;

$dir = 'fonts/';

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(80, 29);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 100, 90); // red
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,299,99,$white);
imagettftext ($image, 21, 8, 16, 23, $color, $dir."Havana.ttf", $_SESSION['rand_code']);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
?>
```

calling captcha image :

```
<img src="captcha.php?e=<?php echo time() ?>">
```

Comment: how are you determining that the session value is wrong?

Comment: When you do `if(!session_id() || session_id() == ''){` it will fail because there is a session id. so your session never starts, and you can't apply a value to the session. turn on error reporting to see this.

Comment: Actually @Ohgodwhy makes a very valid point. Good catch! Removing the `if(!session_id() || session_id() == '')` should fix your problem.

Comment: @cmorrissey : `echo $_SESSION['rand_code']`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy : that is why i have started a session before for check users login

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you're checking `$_SESSION['rand_code']` from the page that is loading the `<img>` resource, in which case you are likely running into a race condition within that 10% margin, whereby the request that updates the session occurred *after* the request that pulls the code from the session.

Remember that in PHP the default session handler will block. So two requests concurrently using the same session will result in the first request acquiring the session lock while each subsequent request waits on that lock to be released before being able to access the session. In a local environment development, where there is virtually no latency between the client and the server this is highly likely since you're loading the page that calls out to `captcha.php` first, and `captcha.php` gets loaded second.

Again, this is all under the assumption that you are doing something like `echo $_SESSION['rand_code']` in the same script where you are doing `<img src="captcha.php?e=<?php echo time() ?>">`

## EDIT

So if you are in fact using the above approach to check and compare the session variable to your displayed captcha image, you will likely run into this out-of-order condition. Instead, you want to try this approach (and you should find that your session variable isn't out of sync at all)...

Create a form in your script like so (say it's called index.php)...

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
    <input type="text" name="captchaString" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<img src="captcha.php?e=<?=time()?>">
```

Now, create submit.php script with the following...

```
<?php
session_start(); // always start the session first

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // if the user POSTs let's check the captcha string against the session
    if (isset($_POST['captchaString']) && $_POST['captchaString'] === $_SESSION['rand_code']) {
        echo "<h1>Success!</h1>";
    } else {
?>
<h1>Failure...</h1>
<p>
Captcha was '<strong><?=$_SESSION['rand_code']?></strong>' and you provided
'<strong><?=$_POST['captchaString']?></strong>'
</p>
<?php
    }
} else {
    // go back to form with captcha and try again
    header('Location: /index.php');
}
```

Load your form at `index.php` and try it out. If you submit the wrong captcha string it will tell you.

Comment: i used `(!session_id() || session_id() == ''` because i have used `session_start()` for check users login , before

Comment: Ahhh, OK. That makes sense. So then it's likely the race condition I mentioned. Can you tell us how you verified the session variables were out of sync?

Comment: so when i remove that condition , i get this error :
`Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in captcha.php on line 3`

Comment: when echo `$_SESSION['rand_code']` , sometimes this value is previous value.

Comment: @AliN11 Right, if you've already started the session before then that's fine. Please see the edit in my answer above.